# Не убирается плавно

Tags: html, jquery, css3, css-animation

Как сделать,что бы убиралось так же плавно как и вылезает?

```
@keyframes stretchRightclose {
 0% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scaleX(0.8);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scaleX(0.6);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scaleX(0.4;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(0.2);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scaleX(0.1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(0);

  }
}
```

Весь пример здесь https://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/pav27dvr/4/

Comment: 80% { transform: scaleX(0.4; *)* }

Comment: Не надо трогать display.

Comment: @KuatMustafin, да, ошибка. Но эта опечатка ни на что не влияет ведь - интерполированное значение при линейной функции будет тем же.

Comment: 80 100 80 100 - что?

Comment: наверное не стоит дважды писать 80% и 100%, в вашем примере на jsfiddle по-разному проставлено для обоих анимаций - возможно опечатка, но всё же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/pav27dvr/6/

```js
$(function () {
  $('.toggle-btn').click(function () {
    $(this).add('#search').toggleClass('open').removeClass('initial');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#search {
  transform-origin: 52px 0%;
  animation: anim-close 2s linear both;
}

#search.open {
  animation: anim-open 2s linear both;
}

#search.initial {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  animation: none;
}

.toggle-btn, .text_search, .btn_search {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16pt;
  position: relative;
}

.text_search:focus, .btn_search:focus {
  z-index: 1;
}

.toggle-btn {
  width: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.toggle-btn.open .if-closed, .toggle-btn .if-open {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-btn.open .if-open {
  display: block;
}

.text_search {
  margin-left: 3px;

}

.btn_search {
  border-left: none;
  width: 33px;
  background:#ffffff;
}

@keyframes anim-open {
   0% { transform: scaleX(0.00); }
  29% { transform: scaleX(1.08); }
  43% { transform: scaleX(0.94); }
  57% { transform: scaleX(1.04); }
  71% { transform: scaleX(0.98); }
  85% { transform: scaleX(1.01); }
 100% { transform: scaleX(1.00); }
}

@keyframes anim-close {
   0% { transform: scaleX(1.00); }
  29% { transform: scaleX(-.08); }
  43% { transform: scaleX(0.06); }
  57% { transform: scaleX(-.04); }
  71% { transform: scaleX(0.02); }
  85% { transform: scaleX(-.01); }
 100% { transform: scaleX(0.00); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="toggle-btn">
  <span class="if-closed">1</span>
  <span class="if-open">2</span>
</a>

<div id="search" class="initial">
  <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" placeholder="   search" class="text_search">
    <input type="button" class="btn_search">
  </form>
</div>
```